# How to get data from the form with add and edit mode

Tags: angular

I have a form to add categories and  I have only one request with create new category and edit this category if has an id. I'm trнing to get data to form if I click edit button.

This method works but his only for create category I'm trying to remake it, if the category has an id then there was an edit mode

Id generated automatically on backend

**Here I clicked on the edit button, but I did not receive the card data in the form**

[image]

**category-modal.component.ts**

```
public submit(): void {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.form.disable();

    const category: ICategory = {
      name: this.form.value.categoryName,
      color: this.form.value.color,
      isPublic: this.form.value.access,
    };

    this.httpService.upsertCategory(category).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.alertService.createSuccessAlert('Category was created');
        this.context.completeWith(category);
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.alertService.createErrorAlert(error.error.message);
        this.form.enable();
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a new function, called `onSubmitEdit(id: number)`, and you pass the ID through the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough context to help you but I certainly spot one common mistake.

```js
const category: ICategory = {
      name: this.form.value.categoryName,
      color: this.form.value.color,
      isPublic: this.form.value.access,
    };

    this.httpService.upsertCategory(category)...
```

Do you see an ID anywhere near your code ? Try providing it in your `category` variable .

Comment: This moment is from the creation of the category, and the Id is not needed there, because it is created on the backend automatically, and when the edit goes, then it is needed